# updated visual studio express, gives error c1853

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've had VSE 2012 for a couple months now while I'm learning to program and I recently updated it to a newer version when it asked to update to "Update 1". Now when I try to compile all my C++ projects I get the following error:
`error C1853: 'Debug\XXXXXX.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)   c:\XXX\visual studio 2012\projects\XXX\XXX XXX.cpp"`. 
I had successfully compiled this program immediately before this update and have tried compiling old projects that I knew for sure worked before the update to no avail. New projects that I create work fine. I don't know that much about headers since I'm just starting out, but the header included by VSE 2012 update 1 is the same exact header that was given in my old projects when I created them before the update (`#include "stdafx.h"`) so I have no idea what's wrong and no idea what to google since googling the error didn't give much help.

Comment: Thanks for noting this situation! I've also updated vs2008 and start giving me this problem (but didn't realized that was related to the upgrade). A Rebuild fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete the precompiled header (Debug\XXXXXX.pch), and then compile it again.

Answer (score 4):

You could try Build> Clean Solution, that should delete your precompiled header too.

Comment: This occasionally happens to any Visual Studio version after an update, including the latest VS2019. Choosing - Clean Solution or Rebuild always fixes the problem.